# Label does not get displayed in javafx

Tags: javafx, properties, borderpane

I have a borderpane in my application. In the bottom part i wanted to set a Label to display the current status of the program for example: "ready", "reading data" and so on.

When I start the application the bottom section does not get displayed. Only after I changed the height of the window manually with my mouse it suddenly pops up. Does anyone know why this happens? I suppose it has something to do with my listener.

main

```
package Sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("View/MainWindow.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Tool-Name");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Accordion?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="604.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller.MainWindow_Controller">
   <center>
      <TabPane fx:id="tpTabs" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="402.0" prefWidth="604.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
         <tabs>
            <Tab fx:id="tDatabase" text="XXXXXXX">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane fx:id="apDatabase" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="bSetDBPath" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX..." />
                        <Button fx:id="bSetHeadFilePath" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="66.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="XXXXXXX..." />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfDBPath" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="255.0" promptText="XXXXXXX" />
                        <TextField fx:id="tfHeadFilePath" layoutX="138.0" layoutY="66.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="255.0" promptText="XXXXXXX" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab text="XXXXXXX">
               <content>
                  <Accordion>
                    <panes>
                      <TitledPane text="XXXXXXX">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button fx:id="bGetNewMembers" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="XXXXXXX" />
                                    <Button fx:id="bGetStatusChange" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="58.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="XXXXXXX" />
                                    <Button fx:id="bRegulation" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="101.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="XXXXXXX" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                        </content>
                      </TitledPane>
                      <TitledPane text="XXXXXXX">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button fx:id="bAdministrationData" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="57.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="XXXXXXX" />
                                    <Button fx:id="bCompareStatus" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                        </content>
                      </TitledPane>
                      <TitledPane text="XXXXXXX">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <Button fx:id="bOrganisation" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="103.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="XXXXXXX" />
                                    <Button fx:id="bDeferredCompensation" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="XXXXXXX" />
                                    <Button fx:id="bCompanyMatching" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="60.0" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="XXXXXXX" />
                                 </children>
                              </AnchorPane>
                        </content>
                      </TitledPane>
                    </panes>
                  </Accordion>
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="tTestCases" text="XXXXXXX">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="tvTestCases" prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="600.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="tcTestCaseId" prefWidth="132.0" text="XXXXXXX">
                                  <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="testCaseId" />
                                  </cellValueFactory>
                              </TableColumn>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="tcPaymentId" prefWidth="150.0" text="XXXXXXX">
                                  <cellValueFactory><PropertyValueFactory property="paymentId" />
                                  </cellValueFactory>
                              </TableColumn>
                           </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </Tab>
            <Tab fx:id="tReports" text="XXXXXXX">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fx:id="tvReports" prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="604.0">
                           <columns>
                              <TableColumn fx:id="tcReportId" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="XXXXXXX" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="tcReportType" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="XXXXXXX" />
                              <TableColumn fx:id="tcCreationDate" editable="false" prefWidth="75.0" text="XXXXXXX" />
                           </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </Tab>
         </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </center>
   <top>
      <MenuBar fx:id="mbMenuBar" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="604.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX">
            <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX">
            <items>
                  <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX">
                    <items>
                      <MenuItem fx:id="miNewVoucher" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="miNewAssociation" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="miNewPensioner" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="miNewRegulation" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="miNewAdministrationCosts" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="miNewPayment" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                    </items>
                  </Menu>
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="miOpenDB" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miImportDatasets" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miSetDBPath" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX">
            <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="miOpenManual" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
                  <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                  <MenuItem fx:id="miSetManualPath" mnemonicParsing="false" text="XXXXXXX" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <Label fx:id="lInfo" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="604.0" text="Bereit" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Controller

```
package Controller;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
public class MainWindow_Controller {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane root;

    @FXML
    private TableView tvTestCases;

    @FXML
    private TableView<?> tvReports;

    @FXML
    MenuBar mbMenuBar;
    @FXML
    private TabPane tpTabs;

    @FXML
    private Label lInfo;

    /**
     * Initialize method to read filepaths and set listeners.
     */
    public void initialize() {
        tpTabs.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BISQUE, null, null)));
        loadListener();
        lInfo.setText("Bereit");
    }

    public void loadListener() {
        root.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                tpTabs.setPrefWidth(root.getWidth());
                tvTestCases.setPrefWidth(root.getWidth());
                tvReports.setPrefWidth(root.getWidth());
            }
        });

        root.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                tpTabs.setPrefHeight(root.getHeight() - mbMenuBar.getHeight()-lInfo.getHeight());
                tvTestCases.setPrefHeight(root.getHeight() - mbMenuBar.getHeight()-lInfo.getHeight());
                tvReports.setPrefHeight(root.getHeight()-mbMenuBar.getHeight()-lInfo.getHeight());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Firstly, why are you controlling sizes of a `BorderPane`'s children manually (`BorderPane` is supposed to manage that for you)? Secondly, your second question should be split into another question, because it has nothing to do with the first problem. (quick hint: don't query database in JavaFX Application thread)

Comment: @kleopatra provided code for reproduction

Comment: @Jai Thank you for your hint regarding the database query. seems very helpful for me.

Comment: worksforme ....

Comment: thats strange. any guess why this happens when I run the code? could it be the listener since the label appears only when i resize the height?

Comment: I managed to delimit the cause to this line   tpTabs.setPrefHeight(root.getHeight() - mbMenuBar.getHeight()-lInfo.getHeight());   when I delete this line the label gets displayed as desired. But my TabPane doesnt resize anymore (obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't adjust the preferred sizes of the nodes during layout. What happens here is that the scene size is determined by calculating the preferred/min/max size ***before the root size is set***. When the root size is set the listeners added in `loadListener` change the preferred sizes which no longer leaves enough room for all of the nodes. Since the `Scene` enforces it's size to be smaller than the actual min size of it's root now, the layouts accomodate to this in a some way, in this case by moving the `Label` out of view.

Do not add those listeners and leave the resizing to the `BorderPane`. For this to work you need to set the max sizes to sizes other than [`Region.USE_PREF_SIZE` (`= -1d/0d = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/constant-values.html#javafx.scene.layout.Region.USE_PREF_SIZE).

The following opening tag for `<TabPane>` simply uses the default value ([`Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#USE_COMPUTED_SIZE)). This way the `TabPane` can grow arbitrary large:

```xml
<TabPane fx:id="tpTabs" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="402.0" prefWidth="604.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
```